# Как повернуть только часть списка, python

Tags: python, список

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как повернуть только часть списка? Имеется ли какой-то быстрый способ?
`list[::-1]` поворачивает весь список.
Мне нужно что бы из `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` , получилось `[4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6]`

Comment: вы бы логику описали целиком. или вам разворачивать надо исключительно варианты с первого по третий элемент любого списка:-)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто переворачиваете нужную часть, которую берёте срезом, а остальное тоже берёте срезом и присоединяете:

```py
lst = lst[3::-1]+lst[4:]
```

Либо если список большой и переворачивать нужно только небольшой его кусок прямо "по месту", то срезом же присваиваете перевёрнутую часть обратно:

```py
lst[:4] = lst[3::-1]
```

Нумерация в срезах в случае `step=-1` у списков какая-то заумная, обратная, не слишком интуитивная.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, а почему последний кусок работает? (`[4, 3, 2, 1] = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, по факту). Нумерация вполне себе интуитивная при `step=-1`, на мой взгляд - просто первый и второй элемент местами меняются (на то и минус), правила же начала и конца отрезка остаются без изменений.

Comment: @Сергей А потому что срезы так устроены - в них можно и присваивать тоже, что очень удобно )   Это как бы ссылка на кусок списка. Поэтому когда в него присваиваешь - присваивается в список. А когда по срезу итерируешься, то берётся как бы копия куска списка.

Comment: @Сергей Ну так то да, логика есть, но вот уже надо 3, а не 4 писать, и [3:-1] написать нельзя, потому что `-1` интерпретируется как от конца списка первый элемент, в общем не тривиально

Comment: А, да, спасибо. Не задумывался о доп. правиле, что конечный элемент при желании до 0 дойти можно только его отсутствием указать, в отличие от прямого шага, где можно и числом. А что 3 надо писать - это логично для меня, мы же с третьего идем. Но я вообще мир объектно вижу, при слове "стул" я зримо стул не представляю, как многие:-)

Comment: То что нужно. Я предполагал что можно таким способ сделать. Но не мог разобраться, что и куда подставлять. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr[0], arr[3] = arr[3], arr[0]
arr[1], arr[2] = arr[2], arr[1]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А что вам помешало обменять сразу все 4 значения одним присваиванием? Вы думаете, что в питоне можно менять только 2 значения? Отнюдь!

Comment: обратите внимание, что просили "быстрый" способ.